# My Kivy program works properly on Windows but on Mac, I have :pygame - Exception: CGL: ANGLE backend can be used only on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

My programme work on windows but not on mac

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import datetime
from functools import partial
import inspect
import threading
import pyodbc 
import json
import argparse
import os
import time
import queue
import sys
import mysql.connector

# Import the required module for text
# to speech conversion
from gtts import gTTS
# prerequisites: as described in https://alphacephei.com/vosk/install and also python module `sounddevice` (simply run command `pip install sounddevice`)
# Example usage using Dutch (nl) recognition model: `python test_microphone.py -m nl`
# For more help run: `python test_microphone.py -h`

import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf

from vosk import KaldiRecognizer
import vosk

import time
import kivy

q = queue.Queue()

my_list = []

os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'


from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
#from kivy.uix.listview import ListView, ListItemButton
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
#from kivy.adapters.listadapter import ListAdapter
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFloatingActionButton
from kivymd.app import MDApp

Builder.load_string("""
<ScrollSlider>:
    ScrollView:
        id: scrlvw
        bar_width: 0
        GridLayout:
            id: grid
            size_hint_y:None
            cols:1
            height: self.minimum_height
            scroll_y: slider.value
            on_touch_move: slider.value = self.scroll_y
    Slider:
        size_hint_x: None
        width: root.width*0.2
        id: slider
        min: 0
        max: 1
        orientation: 'vertical'
        value: scrlvw.scroll_y
        on_value: scrlvw.scroll_y = self.value

""")

class ScrollSlider(BoxLayout):

    def custom_add(self, widget):
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(widget)
        
class EmboutRoute(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user="*****", password="*****", host="*****", port="*****", database="EmbouteillageBenin")
        self.cursor = self.cnx.cursor(buffered=False)

        self.Fond = FloatLayout()       
        self.img = Image(source="JarreTrouee.jpg", allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False)
        # create buttons
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.btn1 = Button(text='Consulter',size_hint=(0.3,0.10))
        self.btn1.bind(on_press=self.consulter)
        #self.btn1.pos_hint={'right': 0.35}
        self.btn2 = Button(text="Embouteillage",size_hint=(0.3,0.10))
        self.btn2.bind(on_press=self.EcranRemplissage)
        self.btn3 = Button(text="Voie libérer",size_hint=(0.3,0.10))
        self.btn3.bind(on_press=self.libererVoie)
        #self.btn2.pos_hint={'right': 0.75}
        self.layout.add_widget(self.btn1)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.btn2)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.btn3)
        #self.label1 = Label(text="Hello")
        #self.micro = Button(markup=True, text="Voix", size_hint=(0.3,0.10))
        self.micro = MDFloatingActionButton(icon="Microphone.jpg", theme_icon_color="Custom")
        self.micro.bind(on_press = self.lancerToutAudio)
        self.micro.pos_hint={'right': 1}

        self.Fond.add_widget(self.img)
        #self.Fond1.add_widget(self.btn1) 
        #self.Fond1.add_widget(self.btn2)
        self.Fond.add_widget(self.layout)
        self.Fond.add_widget(self.micro)
        #self.Fond.add_widget(self.label1)
        #self.cursor.close()
        #cnx.close()
        #return KivyBeninRoute()
        return self.Fond

    def EcranRemplissage (self, instance):
        self.Fond.remove_widget(self.layout)
        if hasattr(self, 'label1'):
            self.Fond.remove_widget(self.label1)      
        # create buttons
        #layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        #self.btn.bind(on_press=self.EncranRemplissage)
        self.btn4 = Button(text="Enregistrer",size_hint=(0.3,0.10))
        self.btn4.bind(on_press=self.EnregEmbouteillage)
        #layout.add_widget(btn)
        #layout.add_widget((btn1))
        self.layout2 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=(15,100,15,100))
        self.Input1 = TextInput(text="Entrez où commence la route",multiline=False, font_size=30, size_hint=(1,.2))
        self.Input2 = TextInput(text="Entrez où finit la route",multiline=False, font_size=30, size_hint=(1,.2))
        self.Input3 = TextInput(text="Entrez le quartier où il y a l'embouteillage",multiline=False, font_size=30, size_hint=(1,.2))
        self.Input4 = TextInput(text="Entrez la ville où il y a l'embouteillage",multiline=False, font_size=30, size_hint=(1,.2))
        self.layout2.add_widget(self.Input1)
        self.layout2.add_widget(self.Input2)
        self.layout2.add_widget(self.Input3)
        self.layout2.add_widget(self.Input4)
 
        
        self.Fond.add_widget(self.layout2)
        self.Fond.add_widget(self.btn4)

        return self.Fond
    

    def int_or_str(self, text):
        """Helper function for argument parsing."""
        try:
            return int(text)
        except ValueError:
            return text

    def callback(self, indata, frames, time, status):
        """This is called (from a; separate thread) for each audio block."""
        if status:
            print(status, file=sys.stderr)
        q.put(bytes(indata))

    def creerEmbouteillage(self, texteAlire, rec):
        x = threading.Thread(target=self.creer_audio_file, args=(texteAlire,),daemon=True)
        x.start()
        x.join()
        my_list.clear()
        y = threading.Thread(target=self.ecoute, args=(rec,))
        y.start()
        time.sleep(3)
        #valeur = y.join()
        #print(valeur + "est valeur")
        #print(my_list + "est liste")
        if my_list == []:
            return ""
        else :
            return str(my_list[0])
        

    def ecoute(self, rec):
        while True:
            data = q.get()
            if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
                motPrononce = json.loads(rec.Result())['text']
                #motPrononce = json.dumps(motPrononce)
                #motPrononce = str(motPrononce)
                #motPrononce = rec.Result().splitlines()[1].split(": ")[1]
                print(motPrononce)
                if motPrononce != '':
                    my_list.append(motPrononce)
                    return True

    def creer_audio_file(self, texteALire):
        # The text that you want to convert to audio
        mytext = texteALire
        # Language in which you want to convert
        language = 'fr'
        # Passing the text and language to the engine,
        # here we have marked slow=False. Which tells
        # the module that the converted audio should
        # have a high speed
        myobj = gTTS(text=mytext, lang=language, slow=False)
        # Saving the converted audio in a mp3 file named
        # welcome
        myobj.save("welcome.wav")
        # Playing the converted file
        #os.system("welcome.wav")
        self.play_audio_file("welcome.wav")



    def play_audio_file(self, AudioFile):
        # Extract data and sampling rate from file
        array, smp_rt = sf.read(AudioFile, dtype = 'float32') 
        # start the playback
        sd.play(array, smp_rt)
        # Wait until file is done playing
        status = sd.wait() 
        # stop the sound
        sd.stop()
    
    def libererVoie(self, instance):
        print(inspect.stack()[1].function)
        self.Fond.remove_widget(self.layout)
        # create buttons
        #layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        #self.btn.bind(on_press=self.EncranRemplissage)
        self.btn6 = Button(text="Acceuil",size_hint=(0.3,0.10))
        self.btn6.bind(on_press=self.PageAcceuil)
        #layout.add_widget(btn)
        #layout.add_widget((btn1))
        self.layout3 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=(15,100,15,100))
        self.Input5 = TextInput(text="Entrez le nom de la ville, du début de la voie, de sa fin ou celui du Quartier", multiline=False, on_text_validate=self.Rechercher, font_size=30, size_hint=(1,.2))
        self.layout3.add_widget(self.Input5)
        
        self.Fond.add_widget(self.layout3)
        self.Fond.add_widget(self.btn6)

        return self.Fond

    def Rechercher(self, instance):
        if hasattr(self, 'scrollslider'):
            self.layout3.remove_widget(self.scrollslider)
        if hasattr(self, 'label3'):
            self.layout3.remove_widget(self.label3)
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM caracteristiques where (DateDebut > current_date()) and (Ville = %s or NomRouteDebut = %s or NomRouteFin = %s or Quartier = %s ) and (DateFin IS NULL)",(self.Input5.text, self.Input5.text, self.Input5.text, self.Input5.text))
        resultat = self.cursor.fetchall()
        self.scrollslider = ScrollSlider()
        for ligne in resultat:
            # Adding button in drop down list
            self.btn = Button(text ='La route de %s à %s de la ville de %s embouteillage à %s' % (ligne[1], ligne[2], ligne[4], ligne[3]), size_hint_y = None, height = 40)
        
            # binding the button to show the text when selected
            if hasattr(self, 'btn'):
                self.btn.bind(on_release=partial(self.selection_change, ligne))
        
            # then add the button inside the dropdown
            self.scrollslider.custom_add(self.btn)
        self.layout3.add_widget(self.scrollslider)
        #self.dropdown.open(instance)
        #self.Fond.add_widget(self.dropdown)
        #self.Fond.add_widget(self.scrollslider)
        return self.Fond
 
 
    def selection_change(self, ligne, *args):
        self.layout3.remove_widget(self.scrollslider)
        self.label2=Label(text='La route de %s à %s de la ville de %s embouteillage à %s est libérée' % (ligne[1], ligne[2], ligne[4], ligne[3]), size_hint_y = None, height = 40)
        self.btn7 = Button(text="Valider",size_hint=(0.1,0.05))
        self.btn7.bind(on_release=partial(self.valider, ligne))

        self.layout3.add_widget(self.label2)
        self.layout3.add_widget(self.btn7)
        print (ligne)
                
    def valider(self, ligne, *args):
        self.cursor.execute("UPDATE caracteristiques SET DateFin = now() WHERE IdEmbouteillage = %s",(ligne[0],))
        self.cnx.commit()
        self.label3 = Label(text="Merci", color=(1,1,1,1), font_size = 72)
        self.layout3.remove_widget(self.btn7)
        self.layout3.add_widget(self.label3)

    def EnregEmbouteillage(self, instance):
        nomDeb = self.Input1.text
        nomFin = self.Input2.text
        nomQuartier = self.Input3.text
        nomVille = self.Input4.text
        self.btn5 = Button(text="Acceuil",size_hint=(0.3,0.10))
        self.btn5.bind(on_press=self.PageAcceuil)
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM caracteristiques where (DateDebut > current_date()) and Ville = %s and (NomRouteDebut = %s or NomRouteFin = %s or Quartier = %s)and (DateFin IS NULL)",(nomVille, nomDeb, nomFin, nomQuartier))
        result = self.cursor.fetchall()
        print(result)
        exist = 0
        self.scrollslider3 = ScrollSlider()
        for ligne in result:
            print (ligne)
            self.label5 = Label(text ='L\'embouteillage suivant sur La route de %s à %s de la ville de %s embouteillage à %s est déjà déclaré' % (ligne[1], ligne[2], ligne[4], ligne[3]), size_hint_y = None, color=(1, 1, 0.5, 1), height = 40)
            self.scrollslider3.custom_add(self.label5)
            exist = 1
        
        if exist == 1:
            self.btn9 = Button(text="Valider quand même",size_hint=(0.3,0.10))
            self.btn9.bind(on_press=self.Forcervalider)
            self.btn9.pos_hint={'right': .75}
            self.layout2.add_widget(self.scrollslider3)
            self.layout2.add_widget(self.btn9) 
        else :
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO caracteristiques(NomRouteDebut,NomRouteFin,Quartier,Ville,DateDebut,DateFin) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, NOW(), null)",(nomDeb, nomFin, nomQuartier, nomVille))
            self.cnx.commit()
            self.label1 = Label(text="Merci", color=(1,1,1,1), font_size = 72)
            self.Fond.add_widget(self.label1)
            self.Fond.remove_widget(self.layout2)
        self.Fond.remove_widget(self.btn4)
        self.Fond.add_widget(self.btn5)
        return self.Fond
    
    def Forcervalider(self, Instance):
        nomDeb = self.Input1.text
        nomFin = self.Input2.text
        nomQuartier = self.Input3.text
        nomVille = self.Input4.text
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO caracteristiques(NomRouteDebut,NomRouteFin,Quartier,Ville,DateDebut,DateFin) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, NOW(), null)",(nomDeb, nomFin, nomQuartier, nomVille))
        self.cnx.commit()
        self.label1 = Label(text="Merci", color=(1,1,1,1), font_size = 72)
        self.Fond.add_widget(self.label1)
        self.Fond.remove_widget(self.layout2)

    def consulter(self, instance):
        self.Fond.remove_widget(self.layout)
        # create buttons
        #layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        #self.btn.bind(on_press=self.EncranRemplissage)
        self.btn8 = Button(text="Acceuil",size_hint=(0.3,0.10))
        self.btn8.bind(on_press=self.PageAcceuil)
        #layout.add_widget(btn)
        #layout.add_widget((btn1))
        self.layout4 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=(15,100,15,100))
        self.Input6 = TextInput(text="Entrez le nom de la ville, du Quatier, du début de la voie ou de la fin de la voie ", multiline=False, on_text_validate=self.RechercherConsulter, font_size=30, size_hint=(1,.2))
        self.layout4.add_widget(self.Input6)
        
        self.Fond.add_widget(self.layout4)
        self.Fond.add_widget(self.btn8)

    def RechercherConsulter(self, instance):
        if hasattr(self, 'scrollslider2'):
            self.layout4.remove_widget(self.scrollslider2)
        if hasattr(self, 'label4'):
            self.layout4.remove_widget(self.label4)
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM caracteristiques where (DateDebut > current_date()) and (Ville = %s or NomRouteDebut = %s or NomRouteFin = %s or Quartier = %s)and (DateFin IS NULL)",(self.Input6.text, self.Input6.text, self.Input6.text, self.Input6.text))
        resultat = self.cursor.fetchall()
        self.scrollslider2 = ScrollSlider()
        for ligne in resultat:
            # Adding button in drop down list
            self.label4 = Label(text ='La route de %s à %s de la ville de %s embouteillage à %s' % (ligne[1], ligne[2], ligne[4], ligne[3]), size_hint_y = None, color=(1, 1, 0.5, 1), height = 40)
        
            # then add the button inside the dropdown
            self.scrollslider2.custom_add(self.label4)
        self.layout4.add_widget(self.scrollslider2)
        #self.dropdown.open(instance)
        #self.Fond.add_widget(self.dropdown)
        #self.Fond.add_widget(self.scrollslider)
        return self.Fond

    def PageAcceuil(self, instance):
        if hasattr(self, 'layout2'):
            self.Fond.remove_widget(self.layout2)
        if hasattr(self, 'layout3'):
            self.Fond.remove_widget(self.layout3)
        if hasattr(self, 'layout4'):
            self.Fond.remove_widget(self.layout4)
        if hasattr(self, "label1"):
            self.Fond.remove_widget(self.label1)
        self.Fond.add_widget(self.layout)
        return self.Fond


    def lancerToutAudio(self, instance):
        consultation = 0
        self.lancerVocal(consultation)

    def lancerVocal(self, consultation):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
        parser.add_argument(
            "-l", "--list-devices", action="store_true",
            help="show list of audio devices and exit")
        args, remaining = parser.parse_known_args()
        if args.list_devices:
            print(sd.query_devices())
            parser.exit(0)
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description=__doc__,
            formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
            parents=[parser])
        parser.add_argument(
            "-f", "--filename", type=str, metavar="FILENAME",
            help="audio file to store recording to")
        parser.add_argument(
            "-d", "--device", type=self.int_or_str,
            help="input device (numeric ID or substring)")
        parser.add_argument(
            "-r", "--samplerate", type=int, help="sampling rate")
        parser.add_argument(
            "-m", "--model", type=str, help="language model; e.g. en-us, fr, nl; default is en-us")
        args = parser.parse_args(remaining)
        try:
            if args.model is None:
                args.model = "model"
            if not os.path.exists(args.model):
                print ("Please download a model for your language from https://alphacephei.com/vosk/models")
                print ("and unpack as 'model' in the current folder.")
                parser.exit(0)
            if args.samplerate is None:
                device_info = sd.query_devices(args.device, 'input')
                # soundfile expects an int, sounddevice provides a float:
                args.samplerate = int(device_info['default_samplerate'])

            model = vosk.Model(args.model)

            if args.filename:
                dump_fn = open(args.filename, "wb")
            else:
                dump_fn = None

            with sd.RawInputStream(samplerate=args.samplerate, blocksize = 8000, device=args.device,
                    dtype="int16", channels=1, callback=self.callback):
                print("#" * 80)
                print("Press Ctrl+C to stop the recording")
                print("#" * 80)

                rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, args.samplerate)
                motPrononce = ""
                phrase = ""

                while True:
                    if consultation == 0:
                        while True:
                            menuPrincipal = self.creerEmbouteillage("Pour consulter dites un; pour déclarer un embouteillage dites deux; pour déclarer une fin d'embouteillage dites trois", rec)
                            if menuPrincipal.__contains__("un"): 
                                consultation = 1
                                break
                            elif menuPrincipal.__contains__("deux"): 
                                consultation = 2
                                break
                            elif menuPrincipal.__contains__("trois"): 
                                consultation = 3
                                break
                            else :
                                z = threading.Thread(target=self.creer_audio_file, args=("Je n'ai pas compris votre choix",),daemon=True)
                                z.start()
                                z.join()
                    if consultation == 1:
                        varVide = 0
                        phrase = self.creerEmbouteillage("Dites le lieu où commence la route, le lieu où elle finit, le quartier ou la ville", rec)
                        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM caracteristiques where DateDebut > current_date() and (DateFin IS NULL)")
                        resultat = self.cursor.fetchall()
                        for i in resultat:
                            if(phrase.__contains__(i[1].lower())|phrase.__contains__(i[2].lower())|phrase.__contains__(i[3].lower())|phrase.__contains__(i[4].lower())):
                                print(i)
                                varVide = 1
                                t = threading.Thread(target=self.creer_audio_file, args=("il y a un embouteillage à" + i[4]+ "Sur la voie"+ i[1]+"à"+i[2]+"précisement à"+ i[3],),daemon=True)
                                t.start()
                                t.join()
                        if varVide == 0 :
                            vide = threading.Thread(target=self.creer_audio_file, args=("il n'y a pas d'embouteillage sur votre itinéraire aujourd'hui",),daemon=True)
                            vide.start()
                            vide.join()
                        break

                    NomRouteDebut = ""
                    NomRouteFin = ""
                    Quartier = ""
                    Ville = ""
                    if consultation == 2:
                        while NomRouteDebut == "" or NomRouteDebut == '':
                            NomRouteDebut = self.creerEmbouteillage("Dites le lieu où commence la route", rec)
                        while NomRouteFin == "" or NomRouteFin == '':
                            NomRouteFin = self.creerEmbouteillage("Dites le lieu où finit la route", rec)
                        while Quartier == "" or Quartier == '':
                            Quartier = self.creerEmbouteillage("Dites le nom du quartier", rec)
                        while Ville == "" or Ville == '':
                            Ville = self.creerEmbouteillage("Dites le nom de la ville", rec)
                        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO caracteristiques(NomRouteDebut,NomRouteFin,Quartier,Ville,DateDebut,DateFin) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, NOW(), null)",(NomRouteDebut, NomRouteFin, Quartier, Ville))
                        self.cnx.commit()
                        ins = threading.Thread(target=self.creer_audio_file, args=("Déclaration faite avec succès",),daemon=True)
                        ins.start()
                        ins.join()
                        break

                    if consultation == 3:
                        while NomRouteDebut == "" or NomRouteDebut == '':
                            NomRouteDebut = self.creerEmbouteillage("Dites le lieu où commence la route", rec)
                        while NomRouteFin == "" or NomRouteFin == '':
                            NomRouteFin = self.creerEmbouteillage("Dites le lieu où finit la route", rec)
                        while Quartier == "" or Quartier == '':
                            Quartier = self.creerEmbouteillage("Dites le nom du quartier", rec)      
                        self.cursor.execute("UPDATE caracteristiques SET DateFin = NOW() WHERE Quartier = %s and NomRouteDebut = %s and NomRouteFin = %s",(Quartier,NomRouteDebut,NomRouteFin))
                        self.cnx.commit()
                        u = threading.Thread(target=self.creer_audio_file, args=("Mise à jour effectuée avec succès",),daemon=True)
                        u.start()
                        u.join()
                        break

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("\nDone")
            parser.exit(0)
        except Exception as e:
            parser.exit(type(e).__name__ + ": " + str(e))
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    EmboutRoute().run()
```

My log is:
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
pygame - Exception: CGL: ANGLE backend can be used only on Windows
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/core/**init**.py", line 71, in core_select_lib
cls = cls()
^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/utils.py", line 353, in new_func
return func(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 44, in **init**
super(WindowPygame, self).**init**(*largs, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/core/window/**init**.py", line 1102, in **init**
self.create_window()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 192, in create_window
super(WindowPygame, self).create_window()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/core/window/**init**.py", line 1477, in create_window
self.initialize_gl()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/core/window/**init**.py", line 1447, in initialize_gl
init_gl(allowed=self.gl_backends_allowed,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/core/gl/**init**.py", line 38, in init_gl
gl_init_symbols(allowed, ignored)
File "kivy/graphics/opengl.pyx", line 1556, in kivy.graphics.opengl.gl_init_symbols
File "kivy/graphics/cgl.pyx", line 109, in kivy.graphics.cgl.cgl_init

[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 1.1.1, git-Unknown, 2023-07-04 (installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivymd/**init**.py")
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

I want to generate the apk
I need to make it work on mac

Comment: Have you tried removing the line: `os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'`?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).